# Forking a process in python

Tags: python

I have updated the question to be more clear 
I want to execute function while printing numbers in background and check the condition.

```
import time

number = [1,100]
t0 = time.time()
for i in number:
    print i
t1= time.time()


def sum_two_numbers():
   t2 = time.time()
   c=1+2
   t3 =time.time()


verify t0<t2 and t3<<t1
```

Comment: With some python? What have you tried? What have you searched for? Have you tried looking up Threading in the Python Standard Library documentation?

Comment: I am unknown to python subprocess and threading, i don't know which will solve the purpose

Comment: So was I before I tried using them. Try using Threading. Look at the examples, search for examples, ... it's all part of learning.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma - Barny is right. You will require both. subprocess to execute the script and threading for simultaneous operation.  For threading - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/python-multithreading-for-dummies   . For subprocess - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @DineshPundkar: threads are not required. `subprocess.Popen()` will run child processes in the background if it does not interact with the child's output. The parent Python code will continue executing, possibly starting new child processes.

Comment: @mhawke - Thanks for catch..!!! Cheers !!!!

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: That's quite a substantial change to your question. You now seem to have only one script and you want to run some code concurrently with a function. That suggests threads or multiprocessing modules.

Comment: Yes as the script two is just doing addition, I thought of adding it to same script.

Answer (score 1):

As the two scripts are completely independent, just use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

```
import subprocess

script1 = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/script1', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'etc'])
script2 = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/script2', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'etc'])
```

That's it, both scripts are running in the background<sup>**1**</sup>. If you want to wait for one of them to complete, call `script1.wait()` or `script2.wait()` as appropriate. Example:

```
import subprocess

script1 = subprocess.Popen(['sleep', '30'])
script2 = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'])
script1.wait()
```

You will find that script 2 will produce its output and terminate before script 1.

If you need to capture the output of either of the child processes then you will need to use pipes, and then things get more complicated.

<sup>**1**</sup> <sub>Here "background" is distinct from the usual *nix notion of a background process running in a shell; there is no job control for example. WRT `subprocess`, a new child process is simply being created and the requested executable loaded. No shell is involved, provided that `shell=False` as per the default `Popen()` option.</sub>

Comment: Hi mhawke, two scripts are independent of each other, I want to run script 1 in background and execute script 2 while script 1 is already running.

Comment: OK. You should update your _question_ with that somewhat important information.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma : answer updated according to your comment.